# Including a body file (that is much like a platform MySQL / PHP / JS) into a wordpress template

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I’ve built an SEO platform that Works with MySQL database and outputs / Inputs to a PHP table.

I’ve made a template in wordpress that has the header and footer from the original theme, and left the body empty so I can call the application / platform.

```
<?php
/*
 Template name: Keywords
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php
include('/body_call/index.php');
?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I’ve tried to place the folder with all the files (body_call) in several places and called the index.php folder hoping that it fills the center of the template.

The index folder is something like this:

```
<html>
<div id="container">    
    <body id="body">
    <?php include('body_call/body.php'); ?>
    </body>
</div>
</html>
```

I know the problem is the calling part because the platform works well if it’s by its self…

And it's probably some worpress specific code that I'm missing.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

Miguel

Answer (score 0):

When you `include` a file from another file you are actually just including it in the file. That means you are actually in first file folder and not second. So if second file needs to include a file wich is stored somewhere else it has to be included by navigating from first file folder to it's actual path. It sounds a little tricky. So to nvigate to upper level if need you should use `../`.

Anyway to avoid any confusion i would suggest to use `absolute path` so where ever the file is called from it will always be able to charge any file from anywhere.

Have a look at `include` [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

an example could be

```
include(/home/user/body_call/index.php');
```

Comment: I apologize but I didn’t understand.
What would be the complete command to to put into a 'keyword.php' template inside a 'buddyboss' theme? As follows:
localhost/pastateste/wp_content/themes/buddyboss/keywords.php
And the folder for the body.php would be localhost/pastateste/body_call/body.php
What would be the command to include the body.php function inside the keywords.php template?
Sorry for the demand, but I’m it’s really getting under my nerves… :)

Comment: <?php include('localhost/pastateste/wp_content/themes/buddyboss/keywords.php'); ?>

Comment: Ok. thanks for your support but it just is not working! I got it to load the body file (the main one) but the images do not apear, the name of the template (keywords) apears in the url (and I think that is routing the site in the wrong way), the images do not apear and when I click on a link it goes to domain/keywords/index.php and it gives a page not found. I think the index.php should apear like: domain/index.php . I tried deleting the keyword from the URL but that would mean making it the home page... This is going really off track. Can anyone help? thanks